# Move to item in array but keep ordering

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I loop through (as part of a javascript banner rotator)

```
<div id="featured" >
<ul> 
<?php
    foreach ($rows as $key => $item) {  
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>"><img src="images/stories/thumb_<?php echo strtolower($item->title);?>.jpg" title="<?php echo $item->title?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title?>"/></a>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>  
</ul>
```

This always starts the rotator at the first item in the array (as returned by the Model). If I click on an item in the array, I want the rotator to start at the clicked item. How do I move to the right element in the array and keep the order the same?

Edit:

To clarify, the items are returned from a database. The items are ordered according to a specific ordering field. What I want to obtain is:

Default action 
1,2,3,4,5

Selected item = 3

3,4,5,1,2

I need to do this in the PHP.

Comment: Use array_search on array_keys result to get the index of your clicked item, then modify the array as array_merge(array_slice($rows, $index, null, true), array_slice($rows, 0, $index, true))

Comment: I don't get this question. There are so many options I could think of but some of them are so obvious that I wonder what restrictions you are facing. I mean how about just transmitting the index and starting to loop at the next index?

Comment: Where are your items stored? A database? XML file? Some webservice? Or just plain hardcoded PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Using Yent's answer

```
$currentLink = htmlspecialchars(JRequest::getURI());
//Loop through and match URLs
foreach ($rows as $key => $item) {
    $arrayLink = $item->link;
    if ($arrayLink == $currentLink) {
        $index = $key;
    }
}
//Reorder the array
$rows = array_merge(array_slice($rows, $index, null, true), array_slice($rows, 0, $index, true));
```

My only problem with this is that due to the thumbnails and the main images of the rotator being driven by the same list, my gallery that this generates moves the items around. Might have to tinker with the js.